# has_many and belongs to access to item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a very simple model I have companies and categories, One company has-many categories, one category has one company.

So my model from Company is like this:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address
  has_many :categories
```

the model from category is:

```
  belongs_to :company
  attr_accessible :name, :status
```

Why I can´t do :

`Category.find_by_company_id`

I try to include `companay_id` in the `attr_accessible` from category, but don't work.

any idea?

I try `Category.find_by_company_id(1)` and obtain this

```
undefined method `find_by_company_id' for #<Class...
```

Comment: Category.find_by_company_id(1234) should work fine.  What error do you get?

Comment: Do you mean `Category.find_by_company_id`? That's not what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it like

```
# 1 is the id which you want to query
@company = Category.find_by_company_id(1)
```

Comment: thanks everyone! I modified the question @steakchaser. I do the consult well, but obtain  'undefine method'

Comment: Plese post your category model

Answer (score 0):

I have to do a migrate to fix the problem.

I have to do

```
rails generate migration AddCompanyToCategory company_id:integer 

rails rake:db
```